# primefaces Cancel button not navigating to previous page

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a `p:commandButton`, which when I click on, I want it to take me to the previous page. This is the code I have used -

```
<p:commandButton id="cancel" value=" Cancel" action="cancel" ajax="false"  process="@this"/>
```

However, when I click on Cancel, nothing happens. Please let me know how I can get my button to navigate to the previous page.

Comment: There's a lot of context missing in the question. As first step I'd remove `ajax="false"` so that the `process` can properly do its job. It should be obvious, but did you think about reading the server logs?

Answer (score 2):

You can use javascript in the oncomplete event of the button.

> oncomplete = "window.history.back();"